# Sequelize join two tables on id

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table of book users and a table of movie users. I'm trying to return a list of the top 100 movie viewers, along with their book profile information. I want to join on ids, but I can't seem to find the right syntax.

This is what I've tried:

```
const mostActiveMovieWatchers = await MovieWatchers.findAll({
      order: [
        ['moviesWatched', 'DESC'],
      ],
      limit: '100',
      include: [{
        model: BookReaders,
        where: { 
          userId: '$MovieWatchers.id$'
        },
        required: true
      }]
    });
```

I've also seen examples where the where clause looks something like this `where: ['userId = id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before join tables you need create association:

```
BookReaders.hasMany(MovieWatchers, { foreignKey: 'bookId' });

MovieWatchers.belongsTo(BookReaders, { foreignKey: 'bookId' });
```

Then, you can use the include option in a find or findAll method call on the **MovieWatchers** model to specify that you want to include the associated **BookReaders** data:

```
MovieWatchers.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: BookReaders,
    },
  ],
}).then((movies) => {
  // array of movies including books
});
```